# Object is undefined Angular2, TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

When i try to check data I am passing with `console.log(details)` it says:

```
CompanyFullName:"asf"
CompanyName:"asf"
IsNewUser:true
LanguageCulture:"asf"
Serviceurl:"asf"
User:Object
Email:undefined
FirstName:undefined
LastName:undefined
Password:undefined
UserName:undefined
```

Code below:

```
        export class SignupPage {

      serviceUrl: string;
      companyName: string;
      companyFullName: string;
      languageCulture: string;
      isNewUser: boolean;
      userName: string;
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      email: string;
      password: string;
      loading: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.isNewUser = true;
      }
      register() {

        let details = {
          Serviceurl: this.serviceUrl,
          CompanyName: this.companyName,
          CompanyFullName: this.companyFullName,
          LanguageCulture: this.languageCulture,
          IsNewUser: this.isNewUser,
          User: {
            UserName: this.userName,
            FirstName: this.firstName,
            LastName: this.lastName,
            Email: this.email,
            Password: this.password
          }
        }
        console.log(details);
     }
```

Comment: where register() is called from ? .

Comment: from a form `<button ion-button (click)="register()" class="continue-button">Register</button>`

Comment: rest of the data is passed correctly, only not this nested object, so I am doing something wrong there

Comment: Can you share html code?

Comment: could you recreate the same problem on plunker ?

Comment: Seems like all your variables could be undefined when assigning. Have you checked that they actually have values before assigning? Just try to console log `this.userName` before assigning the values to `details`

Comment: you are right AJT_82, i did some spelling mistake and variables were not defined at all, thank you

Comment: No problem, glad it got sorted out! :)